# NodeJS cannot create array with nested query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

After a succesful query to Mongodb to get a list of news, for the news that have a link attached i search for link details in the database but after i set them inside the modified news object i cannot push it to an array. Why does this happen?

```
var newsarray = []
for(i=0;i<newsfound.length;i++){
    if(!newsfound[i].link._id){
        newsarray.push(newsfound[i])
    } else {
        var tempnew = newsfound[i];
        db.findOne('links',{'_id':tempnew.link._id},function(err,linkdetails){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                tempnew.linkdetails = linkdetails;
                newsarray.push(tempnew)
            }
        })
    }
}
console.log(newsarray)
```

The result of this is an array without the link containing news or if i try a few changes an array with the original news without the added details.

Comment: It's an **asynchronous environment**. That's why you pass a callback to `db.findOne()`.

Comment: What do you mean? What should i do? I tried with async but still it fails to get the modified news...

Comment: Why the downvote? I obviously understand the asynchronous context but fail to see why the array.push(modifiednew) fails. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an asynchronous function inside a for loop. The reason is that the for loop gets executed before even any callback could come, and hence the scope gets messed up.

You should use recursive function (self calling) which will prevent the next async call before the previous is over.

```
var i = 0;
function fn() {
    // your logic goes here,
    // make an async function call or whatever. I have shown async in a timeout.
    setTimeout(function () {
        i += 1;    
        if (i < newsfound.length) {
            fn();
        } else {
            // done
            // print result
        }
    });

}
```

**Update:**

For your use case,

```
var newsarray = []
var i = 0;

function done() {
    // done, use the result
    console.log(newsarray);
}

function fn() {
    if (!newsfound[i].link._id) {
        newsarray.push(newsfound[i]);
        i += 1;
        if (i < newsfound.length) {
            fn();
        } else {
            done();
        }
    } else {
        var tempnew = newsfound[i];
        db.findOne('links', {'_id':tempnew.link._id}, function(err, linkdetails){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                tempnew.linkdetails = linkdetails;
                newsarray.push(tempnew);
                i += 1;
                if (i < newsfound.length) {
                    fn();
                } else {
                    done();
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think i get the general idea but in this case how should i do it? I mean i have to use an if...else... and a db.query. Do i have to use the same technique inside too? Could you please explain a little more specific?

Comment: Actually what if i don't want to print the result but want to push it into an array? That's where the problem begins...

Comment: @Aggelos see the updated answer, is this what you want?

Comment: You can't imagine how much you've helped me... Thank you!!! You are great!!! Can't describe how beautiful your code looks to me right now!!!!